# How to bypass filter which blocks < charachter?

Tags: xss, javascript, reflected-xss

I am practicing  reflected xss .I found a page in my lab which gives back the input in response of the request.But the application is sanitizing anything which comes after a < character because of which I can't use any tags.What is actually happening is when I give input as < it is being encoded and then sent to server , then server is decoding and checking for < character . If I use > character in addition to < character then every thing in between them is getting sanitized. Is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: You could try to nest tags or use unexpected/invalid HTML contructs. E.g. `<foo<bar>>`.

Comment: @Arminius as soon as the application sees < character every thing after < will be sanitized

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you, that is helpful. If you get to know any solution please ping me